# How do I correct this error? ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snowflake.connector'

Tags: import, package, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snowflake.connector'

I only see snowflake.py in my "available packages". I do not see snowflake.connector in the list. I have tried adding other packages with similar names but they are not what I need.

I am using pycharm, trying to run this line:  import snowflake.connector as snow

Comment: Hi - you'll need to give a lot more information than that in order for someone to be able to help you. What are you actually doing? What's your environment? What tools are you using? What's the code (I assume it's a piece of code) that is giving this error? Please update your question with additional information - don't add it in a comment

Comment: You should try with installing [necessary packages](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html#install-in-tool-window) using `pip` or `conda` from package repositories. [Installing the Python Connector](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/python-connector/python-connector-install)